# Ruby CSV::Row remove new line

Tags: ruby, csv

I am opening a CSV file and then converting it to JSON.  This is all working fine except the JSON data has `\n` characters in the string.  These are not part of the last element as far as I can tell from printing it and trying to chomp it. When I print the `row` it does have `\n`

```
require 'csv'
require 'json'
def csv_to_json (tmpfile)
    JSON_ARRAY = Array.new
    CSV.foreach(tmpfile) do |row|
        print row[row.length - 1]
        if row[row.length - 1].chomp! == nil
            print row
        end
        JSON_ARRAY.push(row)
     end
     return JSON_ARRAY.to_json
 end
```

The JSON then looks like this when it is returned

```
["field11,field12\n",
 "field21,field22\n"]
```

**How can I remove these new line characters?**

EDIT:
These are `CSV::Row` objects and do not support string operations like `chomp` or `strip`

`tmpfile` is in the format

```
field11,field21
field21,field22
```

Comment: Can you please make a minimal self-contained correct example? We don't know what `tmpfile` looks like, we don't know what happens with JSON_ARRAY, and to my best knowledge, `CSV::Row#to_s` will result in `["a", "b", "c"]`, not in `a,b,c\n`. Unless you're using `CSV::Row#to_csv` somewhere, which I can't see, I don't know how you're getting that result.

Comment: @Amadan I added more details such as file format.  Also from the rdoc for `CSV::Row`, it says that `to_s` is `Alias for: to_csv`

Comment: Just tried this myself and I'm not seeing the same behavior you are.  When I print the last field in row, there are no newlines in it.

Comment: Are you running this on Windows?  The CSV lib docs suggest there might be some wackiness if the file isn't opened in binary mode on Windows.

Comment: @SomeGuy I don't see it when I print the last field either. I'm doing this on OSX 10.9 Ruby 2.1.1

Comment: @NuclearGhost sorry, I misunderstood what you meant when you said you saw the \n when you print row.  Still though, a simple 'print row' isn't producing newlines for me either.

Comment: Running your code (after downcasing `JSON_ARRAY` - can't have a constant assignment in a method), I'm getting `[["field11","field21"],["field21","field22"]]` for `csv_to_json('file.csv')` - nothing even remotely like your `["field11,field12\n","field21,field22\n"]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it to work using a `map!` after the fact

```
json_array.map! { |row| row = row.to_s.chomp! }
```

You could also do the `to_s.chomp!` inside of the loop. This wasn't an option for me because I needed the regular objects to do some calculations before returning the json

Comment: You don't need to use a bang on both array and individual strings. Either one will work `json_array.map! { |row| row = row.to_s.chomp }` will create new strings and point array reference to these new strings. While `json_array.map { |row| row = row.to_s.chomp! }` will modify array elements themselves.

Answer (score 4):

### Set the `row_sep` to `nil`.

```rb
JSON_ARRAY.push( row.to_s( row_sep: nil ) )
```

or

```rb
JSON_ARRAY.push( row.to_csv( row_sep: nil ) )
```

As a comment pointed out, `CSV::row#to_s` is an alias for `CSV::row#to_csv`, which adds a row separator after each line automatically. To get around this you can just set the `row_sep` to `nil` and it will not add `\n` at the end of each row.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way:

```
File.read(tmpfile).split("\n")
```

By the way, if you want to remove the newline from the string, you could use `String::strip` method.

```
CSV.foreach(tmpfile) do |row|
  # here row should be an array.
  p row
end
```

Comment: I don't have an issue with splitting the file on the new lines, but removing the `\n` from the `CSV::Row`

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
CSV.foreach(tmpfile) do |row|
    print row[row.length - 1]
    if row[row.length - 1].chomp! == nil
        print row
    end
    row.map{|cell| cell.strip!}
    JSON_ARRAY.push(row)
 end
```

The row doesn't support stripping, but the cells do.

Comment: These are `CSV::Row` and don't support string operations like `strip`